# Como puedo ejecutar dos procedimientos en un paquete plsql

Tags: plsql

estoy creando un paquete en el que tengo un procedimiento que inserta datos en una tabla y otro procedimiento que borra datos pero me está dando error.
Lo que tengo es lo siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE funcionesJobs AS
    procedure addJob;
    procedure deleteJob;
END funcionesJobs;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY funcionesJobs
IS
    PROCEDURE addJob (
        p_jobID VARCHAR2,
        p_jobTitle  VARCHAR2,
        p_minSalary NUMBER,
        p_maxSalary NUMBER
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO JOBS VALUES(p_jobID, p_jobTitle, p_minSalary, p_maxSalary);
    END;
    
    PROCEDURE deleteJob(
    
    AS
    BEGIN
        DELETE * FROM JOBS where ID=''
    )
;
END;

BEGIN
    funcionesJobs.addJob('NUEVO','Nuevo puesto', 500, 999);
    --funcionesJobs.deleteJob('NUEVO')
END;
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
Errors: PACKAGE FUNCIONESJOBS
Line/Col: 10/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

   language

Line/Col: 15/5 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:

   end not pragma final instantiable persistable order
   overriding static member constructor map
```

Answer (score 0):

Son unos errores de sintaxis sencillos que se resuelven si uno mira [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/packages.htm#LNPLS00905):

- Cuando terminas de definir el `PACKAGE`, tienes que usar `/` para que se ejecute lo que está en el buffer hasta ahora y así, cuando se ejecute la instrucción del package body, encuentre la definición del package y compile correctamente.
- En el package, los procedimientos deben declarar los parámetros que usan. Los tienes sin parámetros pero en el body tienen cuatro parámetros (en el segundo procedure ni siquiera cierras el paréntesis).
- Se escribe `CREATE PACKAGE BODY nombre_pkg AS` y tienes `IS`. Peeero, para los procedure sí se usa IS en vez de AS.
- No cerraste el `PACKAGE BODY` en tu ejemplo.

Queda algo como:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE funcionesJobs AS
    procedure addJob(p_jobID VARCHAR2, p_jobTitle  VARCHAR2, p_minSalary NUMBER, p_maxSalary NUMBER);
    procedure deleteJob(algo NUMBER, otro_algo VARCHAR2,...);
END funcionesJobs;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY funcionesJobs AS
    PROCEDURE addJob (
        p_jobID VARCHAR2,
        p_jobTitle  VARCHAR2,
        p_minSalary NUMBER,
        p_maxSalary NUMBER
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO JOBS VALUES(p_jobID, p_jobTitle, p_minSalary, p_maxSalary);
    END;
    
    PROCEDURE deleteJob(algo NUMBER, otro_algo VARCHAR2,...)
    IS
    BEGIN
        DELETE * FROM JOBS where ID=''
    );
    END;
-- Te faltaba cerrar el package body...
END funcionesJobs;

-- Supongo que intentas llamar uno de los procedures
BEGIN
    funcionesJobs.addJob('NUEVO','Nuevo puesto', 500, 999);
    --funcionesJobs.deleteJob('NUEVO')
END;
```